# 2012 R2 print server not showing file names on Event id 307

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing, windows-event-log, print-server, eventviewer

I'm having trouble logging detailed information on my print server. Operational logging is enabled and working. The event ID 307 displays information about the jobs printed, but instead of the file name it shows: "Print document".

I refeered to the MS KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2938013

I downloaded this update for 2012 R2: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42334

but when I try to install it , it says that the update is already installed. Even though I search for it on my installed updates and it doesn't show.

However, there's no file name on events 307.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution. There's a local computer policy:  Computer configuration >> Administrative Templates >> Printers>> **allow job name in event logs**

Then I restarted the server and voilá!

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows+R to run the run prompt and type gpedit.msc and press enter key.
[image]

Then go to Computer Configuration, Admistrative Templates, Printers, and Allow Job Names in Event Log.

[image]